# Proxy Websocket Requests in Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, go, websocket, http-proxy

I have a rails app and a Golang service. Rails app is user facing app with UI. Part of the requests from frontend are being routed to golang service for certain functionalities. Till now we had only HTTP requests coming from UI.

Now we have websockets functionality in UI. So we need to route these websocket requests to Golang service through Rails Application. Basically Rails application controls the authentication/authorization part. So we need to route the requests through Rails app.

We explored https://github.com/ncr/rack-proxy to route the requests, but we were not able to route the websocket request properly. We tried following code, where web socket requests are received on *ws://localhost:3000/ws/v1/stat* are sent to *ws://localhost:4000/ws/v1/stats* using the following code.

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true
require 'rack-proxy'
module Proxy
  ENV['SERVICE_URL'] ||= 'http://guides.rubyonrails.org'
  class GoServiceProxy < Rack::Proxy
    def perform_request(env)
      request = Rack::Request.new(env)
      # use rack proxy for anything hitting our host app at /example_service
      # if request.path =~ %r{^/example_service}
      if request.path =~ %r{stats}
        backend = URI(ENV['SERVICE_URL'])
        # most backends required host set properly, but rack-proxy doesn't set this for you automatically
        # even when a backend host is passed in via the options
        env["HTTP_HOST"] = 'localhost:4000'
        # This is the only path that needs to be set currently on Rails 5 & greater
        #env['PATH_INFO'] = ENV['SERVICE_PATH'] || '/configuring.html'
        # don't send your sites cookies to target service, unless it is a trusted internal service that can parse all your cookies
        env['HTTP_COOKIE'] = ''
        super(env)
      else
        @app.call(env)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But when I curl on *ws://localhost:3000/ws/v1/stat*, I get 101 response but the messages sent from go service are not coming. Following screenshot is the response I get:

```
curl -v --request GET 'http://localhost:3000/ws/v1/stats' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Upgrade: websocket' \
--header 'Connection: upgrade' \
--header 'Sec-WebSocket-Key: x3JJHMbDL1EzLkh9GBhXDw==' \
--header 'Sec-Websocket-Version: 13'
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, GET is already inferred.
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connection failed
* connect to ::1 port 3000 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3000 (#0)
> GET /ws/v1/stats HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:3000
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Upgrade: websocket
> Connection: upgrade
> Sec-WebSocket-Key: x3JJHMbDL1EzLkh9GBhXDw==
> Sec-Websocket-Version: 13
>
< HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
< sec-websocket-accept: HSmrc0sMlYUkAGmm5OPpG2HaGWk=
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< X-Request-Id: 957758f9-d762-43d0-bffb-fdd72efbfbc1
< X-Runtime: 0.002848
<
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Is there any way we can proxy websocket requests through Rails Application?

Comment: Is there anything you've tried so far? You should post some code that you're written so far so that the community has something to start with. Also, since you HAVE to send your websockets to the Rails app, my go-to option would be to translate the websockets requests in Rails, and forward them to an equivalent http call in the Go service.

Comment: @Jay I have added my changes to proxy web socket request to go service and the corresponding response we are receiving. Thanks.

Comment: Does you go service accept websocket connections? You might not need to proxy to a websocket at all.

Comment: Please do not post images of plaintext as [they are not appropriate on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3784008). Please copy and paste plaintext into your question.

Comment: @Jay yes I have tested my go service it accepts web socket connections. I need to proxy the requests because my go service does do authentication. It is done by Rails service and I don't want to expose the Goservice to web at it is one more overhead. I have to proxy the requests to goservice through rails service.

Comment: @anothermh Thanks so much for the correction. I added the plain text.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like an A/B problem.

Your real issue is authenticating WebSocket users on the Go application using Rails credentials.

#### Why not proxy the connections

Your latest solutions appears to be to have Rails authenticate the users and then proxy the connection to the Go app.

This solution has a number of security concerns as well as a big performance penalty. For example:

1. (security) the Go app assumes all connections are "safe", making it a convenient vector for cyber attacks by having an attacker try to connect to that service directly or through a different route (bypassing the Rails app).
2. (performance) all network traffic and connections are doubled (if not more than doubled, actually), placing a higher load on the Rails app.

#### A better solution

A better solution would be to write a small Rails AUTH app that will provide authentication services to the Go application.

The Go applications **should** perform authentication. Assuming any network traffic is safe (even traffic that appears to be local) is a recipe for disaster.

These authentication services might test for long term authentication tokens (poor security) or one time authentication tokens (better security) that were pre-negotiated through the Rails user facing app.

WebSocket connections will be made directly to the Go application (using, most likely, either a subdomain or URL routing) and validated using the authentication micro-service.

Good luck!